# Save caption style / create preset

Tags: video, premiere, editing, subtitles

I'm doing a lot of small videos, often using the same open captions styles. But for every video, I have to re-enter every parameter (font, font size, color, etc.), repeating those steps for ever caption object. (I use different captions objects for different persons talking, simply changing the color.)
That means that I sometimes have to open the very same parameters 4 times, with the only difference being the color.

Is there a faster way to do that? I would have assumed you can save a "caption style preset" or something similar, but I could not find such a feature. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on what software you're using - would you be able to clarify?

In Premiere Pro you can use Essential Graphics to drive your captions (there is a number of captions presets in the EG panel already, just go to Essential Graphics\Captions and Subtitles and select the one that best suits your video) - the editor has plenty of useful options and you can save your styles as 'Masters' and reuse that style for each subsequent video. Alternatively, you can create your own Essential Graphics template for captions via After Effects to have full control over them.

More info on [Adobe's help site](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/essential-graphics-panel.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer ; sorry I did not mention I was using Premiere, because I added the Premiere tag and I thought it would be obvious, but it's actually not. So yes, I am indeed using Adobe Premiere Pro :) I'll check it out after work and come back to you ! Thanks a lot for your answer, it seems like it's what I need

Comment: Just a note, I'm not using Title objects to caption my video, I am using the Captions tool.

Comment: You did tag it, I'm sorry I missed that :D
If you're in a position to update your Premiere Pro, I'd urge you to do so because the Essential Graphics panel does give you some great options for titles of all kinds. If you're worried about overwriting your current version, you can install an additional, newer, version as opposed to updating directly (you may know this already but, just in case!).